# CSS web page scale in mobile

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, mobile-website

I'm trying to figure out why this http://mobile.kendallarneaud.me/mobile/wemusic/#player is displaying as if it is "zoomed out" as to fit all in the mobile browsers?

Can anyone give me some insights? I don't want that it should give me a much normal scaling...

http://kendallarneaud.me/mobile/wemusic/#player seems to show it at normal scale

Comment: Could you be more precise on what you expect to see and what you actually see ?

Comment: Well on my mobile browser I should see the interface at normal scaled ratio...what I actually see is the interface looking scaled to fit all rather than the device width...it looks "zoomed out" don't you see that?

Comment: everything looks shrinked...smaller..1/2 the size its suppose to be...not sure how to be more precise to be honest...this is weird for me

Comment: Ok I think i figured out WHAT the problem is go to http://mobile.kendallarneaud.me/mobile/wemusic/#player then visit the url above...what is causing this?

Comment: to see how it looks like on mobile, use Chrome and its Mobile emulation: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation

Comment: Thanks I did which is why i am puzzled by the difference when accessed through different urls...Have you tried accessing it via mobile browsers instead?

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be missing this very important line, which is step 1 for responsive design:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L8